# How to determine movement with Accelerometer data Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, core-motion

I'm getting three values as X, Y, and Z from the phone's accelerometer. However, I'm confused as to how I can use these values.

I'm building a fitness app and I want to determine when the user started running, walking, and became stationary.

This is my code as of now:

```
func updateLabels(data: CMAccelerometerData?, error: Error?){
        guard let accelorometerData = data else { return }

        let formatter = NumberFormatter()
        formatter.minimumFractionDigits = 1
        formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 2

        let x = formatter.string(for: accelorometerData.acceleration.x)
        let y = formatter.string(for: accelorometerData.acceleration.y)
        let z = formatter.string(for: accelorometerData.acceleration.z)

        //Do Something With Values
        self.ex = "X : " + x!
        self.ey = "Y : " + y!
        self.ez = "Z : " + z!

    }
```

Comment: I don't think there's an API or formula where you can feed these values and easily know what the user is doing. My suggestion would be to start by printing them to the console and observing their behaviour as you move your device.

Comment: I've tried doing but the values are very random and there isn't a clear pattern that I can use to distinguish different activities.